# Read and write data through USB port

Tags: c, linux, libusb

Two LoRa modules are connected through USB ports in Linux environment. The specification of two LoRa modules is 
https://techship.com/download/acsip-s76s-product-brief-datasheet-v2

One LoRa module is transmitter and other is receiver. I am new to USB based programming.

My question is how to detect the USB device and read/write the packets through USB.

Comment: may be you forgot to put some `code` in here ?

Comment: I want to know about the steps and guidelines to proceed.

Comment: @kishore, It will be emulated as ttyUSB0 or ttyACM0 serial port in your linux environment..You can use this [http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-Programming-HOWTO/x115.html]. Instead of MODEMDEVICE, use your device file "/dev/ttyUSB0 or /dev/ttyACM0"

Comment: How exactly have you connected these modules to your Linux system? The datasheets you have linked are about naked modules. Or do you instead use S76SXB or a similar device?